# return list of similar tagged urls mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

urls table

| url | date |
| --- | --- |
| http://url1 | a |
| http://url2 | b |
| http://url3 | c |
| http://url4 | d |

tags table

| url | tags |
| --- | --- |
| http://url1 | x |
| http://url1 | y |
| http://url2 | x |
| http://url2 | y |
| http://url3 | x |
| http://url3 | z |
| http://url4 | z |

the url table has url data and tags table has url tags data.

I want urls having similar tags ordered by the count of similar tags

eg1:
if i want URLs which has similar tags as URL 'http://url1'
the query should return

| url | similar tags |
| --- | --- |
| http://url2 | x,y |
| http://url3 | x |

'http://url1' has x,y

'http://url2' has x,y in common with 'http://url1'

'http://url3' has x in common with 'http://url1'

eg2:
for 'http://url4'

| url | similar tags |
| --- | --- |
| http://url3 | z |

'http://url3' has z in common with 'http://url4'

so urls should be returned order by similar tags count (desc)

note: The query should only return similar urls for specified url like in eg1 'http://url1'

i am not good at larger sql queries, so i need to ask this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't url3 have `x,z` for its similar tags?

Comment: for url1 and url3 has only x common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    urls.url,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.tags) as "similar tags"
FROM urls
INNER JOIN tags t1 ON t1.url=urls.url
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON t2.url='http://url1' and t2.tags = t1.tags
GROUP BY urls.url
```

Optionally you can add a `WHERE urls.url <> 'http://url1'`   (Before the `GROUP BY`, and after the last `INNER JOIN`)

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8263024b5cf74f47cae5785cd3ba396)

EDIT: Starting from the table `tags`, like @Andrea_86 suggest, also works:

```
SELECT 
   t1.url, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(t1.tags) as "similar tags" 
FROM tags t1 
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON t2.url='http://url1' and t2.tags = t1.tags 
GROUP BY t1.url
```

Comment: why did you start from urls? you can't simply start from tags t1 and join it to tags t2?
someyhing like:
SELECT
    t1.url,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t1.tags) as "similar tags"
FROM  tags t1 
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON t2.url='http://url1' and t2.tags = t1.tags
GROUP BY t1.url